How Can I install Packages Into a Test Directory?
I want to install a list of packages under a certain directory. I have seen this answer but It doesn't fulfill my needs.
What I want to do is the following:

Select a folder to include all files related to the ubuntu focal packages.
Install list of packages to the selected folder
Do static analysis on the package files (this is not related to the Q).

And repeat this for selected other ubuntu versions.
I don't want to break my system. And I want this test environment to be managed easily. What would be the best practice? I am thinking of chroot but Im not sure if it would work as expected with apt.
I am currently using ubuntu focal 20.04 lts. But as I said, I am not willing to change current configuration.

relevance to Ubuntu?

@graham where should I ask? And if this is not relevant, how the question I quoted was relevant?

I don't see a Ubuntu product/release detail, but most packages are packaged to be installed at specific locations (directories) in your system, meaning your control is via location of those directories (mostly setup at install time, but can be changed any other time too).

Did you try any of these answers?

If you simply want to analyze the files without running anything, you can extract a deb file. And, technically, you could probably run the bin file from that local directory but there's no telling if it would work properly or expect, for example, configuration files in /etc that would be in your local directory ./etc instead of under root in /etc

You can install a Linux-VM (Ubuntu-VM) under Linux(Ubuntu) and install the packages there, to analyze them. Or inside a container like docker, podman, ... .

This question seems on-topic to me. Apt works in a chroot; that's a good solution. Most testers I know use a VM because it's more convenient than a chroot for them..

@guiverc Hi, Sorry for being a rookie, I have updated my question by explaining which packages I am looking for, and which version currently i am using

@mchid Yes, It was a mistake, I am actually looking for ubuntu packages. I already managed to get some debian pkgs.

Does this answer your question? How to reverse engineer deb file?

@ArturMeinild No unfortunately. Im not interested with where package files goes after installation. I just need to keep all files in a closure and use the utils apt provides

The most simple and straightforward way is probably to set up a VM. The snapshot features will likely be super useful.

Hello All, I have tried debootstrap with chroot and It turned out being very convenient for me. Should I write an answer myself? Or should I just delete the post?
